# Unmarshaling json into a type

Tags: go, struct

I get the following data:

```
{
  "timestamp": "1526058949",
  "bids": [
    [
      "7215.90",
      "2.31930000"
    ],
    [
      "7215.77",
      "1.00000000"
    ]
  ]
}
```

via websocket and I would like to unmarshall it into

```
type OrderBookItem struct {
    Price  string
    Amount string
}

type OrderBookResult struct {
    Timestamp string            `json:"timestamp"`
    Bids      []OrderBookItem `json:"bids"`
    Asks      []OrderBookItem `json:"asks"`
}
```

Unmarshal it with:

```
s := e.Data.(string)
d := &OrderBookResult{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), d)
if err == nil {
 ....
} else {
 fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
```

But I keep getting the error:

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field
>   OrderBookResult.bids of type feed.OrderBookItem

When I change the struct into

```
type OrderBookResult struct {
        Timestamp string     `json:"timestamp"`
        Bids      [][]string `json:"bids"`
        Asks      [][]string `json:"asks"`
}
```

it works. I would like them to be defined as `float64` which is what they are. What do I have to change?

Comment: You've found a structure that works, what is your question?

Comment: if you see the error is due to `OrderBookItem` is a struct not an array of items that's why the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says:

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field
>   OrderBookResult.bids of type feed.OrderBookItem

We cannot convert OrderBookResult.bids which is a slice of string into OrderBookItem which is struct

Implement `UnmarshalJSON` interface to convert array into objects for `price` and `amount` of `OrderBookItem` struct. Like below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type OrderBookItem struct {
    Price  string
    Amount string
}

func(item *OrderBookItem) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte)error{
    var v []string
    if err:= json.Unmarshal(data, &v);err!=nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    item.Price  = v[0]
    item.Amount = v[1]
    return nil
}

type OrderBookResult struct {
    Timestamp string            `json:"timestamp"`
    Bids      []OrderBookItem   `json:"bids"`
    Asks      []OrderBookItem   `json:"asks"`
}

func main() {
    var result OrderBookResult
    jsonString := []byte(`{"timestamp": "1526058949", "bids": [["7215.90", "2.31930000"], ["7215.77", "1.00000000"]]}`)
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &result); err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", result)
}
```

[Playground working example](https://play.golang.org/p/LIo43rAZSXy)

For more information read GoLang spec for [Unmarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler)

Comment: You don't need all that unnecessary interface conversions, just pass a [2]string array to json.Unmarshall https://play.golang.org/p/kRYXtDZiIB7

Comment: @mpm yes we can do that that's why I have mentioned in my answer that it is a slice of string in json. So I have converted into same object types. If OP wants to insert in same struct without changing the struct. But thanks for notifying.

Comment: I think mpm was saying that you can still achieve putting the data in a struct but don't need to do type conversion on the way

Answer (score 2):

You are treating your bids as a structure of two separate strings, when they are really a slice of strings in the JSON. If you change OrderBookItem to be

```
type OrderBookItem []string
```

which is how you have defined them in the second bit, which works.

To access the values you just have to do:
price := d.Bids[0]
amount := d.Bids[1]

Comment: thanks that works. Is it possible to define the types to floats which is what they are? If I `fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(o.Asks[1][0]))`I get `string`

Comment: @Tino, yes, using the string option: Bids []float64 `json:"bids,string"`. See [json.Marshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) for other options.